# Server For Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm a new developer, and I just started to learn about servers and push notifications. I have replicated a match app in which users select other people that they liked. If two users like each other they form a match. I would like to send a notification every time someone matches with another person. How would I go about doing this if I was using firebase for storage?

Comment: Did you go through the [Firebase Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) guide and in particular the guide on [Sending Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message)? Then check out [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) too see how to notify a user when something interesting happens.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using firebase storage or firebase real-time database as a backend? I assume you meant firebase database. You can trigger a notification by monitoring change at a specific database path/ref using cloud functions. Check out following samples from firebase on how to use cloud functions: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications